# How do you deserialize a simple xml node value into a composite type?

Tags: c#, serialization, xml-serialization

I have xml that looks something like this:

```
<Policy>
  <Number>10-13-123123</number>
</Policy>
```

And a types like this:

```
class Policy
{
    [DataMember]
    PolicyNumber Number {get;set;}
}
class PolicyNumber
{
    [DataMember]
    public int Num1 {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public int Num2 {get;set;}
    [DataMember]
    public int Num3 {get;set;}
}
```

I need to run a method to split the Xml value up into the 3 properties

How can I get code to run during the XmlSerializer deserialize process to process the Xml value into a new instance of the composite type?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must implement `IXmlSerializable` in one (or both) of these classes to support what you want.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.ixmlserializable.aspx